# The easiest way to get centroids of triangles tiling sphere

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I need to tile a unit sphere with N equal equilateral spherical triangles and get an array of the coordinates {Phi, Theta} of the centroids of those triangles. 
What is the most straightforward way to do this in Mathematica? Are there any built-in functions that might help?

Comment: It is mathematically impossible to tile a sphere with an arbitrary $N$ equilateral spherical triangles.

Comment: Ok, that is not the most crucial part. What about tiling with just N triangles?

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Mathematica 11.3

Comment: And although I understand your question, your terminology is a bit off. I know *tiling* only in reference to a 2D surface and subdividing a 3D sphere is if anything done with [tetrahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron).

Comment: @halirutan:  It makes no sense trying to tile a sphere with (three-dimensional) tetrahedra.  No sense at all.

Comment: What I am interested in is only a sphere surface discretization using triangles.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This is why I have written: "subdivide". I wasn't sure if the OP wants a tiling of the sphere's surface, a subdivision of the 3D sphere for e.g. FEM, or a mesh using triangles that approximates the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure I understood what you are seeking, but let's give it a try. Let us look at a simple function that subdivides a triangle in the following way:

```
div[expr_] := expr /. Triangle[pts : {a_, b_, c_}] :> 
  With[{ab = Mean[{a, b}], ac = Mean[{a, c}], bc = Mean[{b, c}]},
    Triangle /@ {{a, ab, ac}, {ab, b, bc}, {ab, bc, ac}, {ac, bc, c}}
  ]

tri = Triangle@Table[{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}, {phi, {0, 2 Pi/3, 4 Pi/3}}];
GraphicsRow[
 Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Gray], #}] & /@ {tri, div[tri]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, let us take a look at an Icosahedron

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can access the triangles of this polyhedron using `PolyhedronData` as well. There might be an easier way to do this, but I'm not digging right now:

```
pts = Triangle[N@PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Vertices"][[#]]] & /@ 
   PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "Faces"];
```

Now, we can use the `div` function to subdivide each of the triangles as often as we want

```
subpts = Nest[div, pts, 2];
Graphics3D[subpts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The last step is the most important one: Now we take each vertex and *normalize* is. This means in 3D it will be projected onto the surface of the unit sphere

```
Graphics3D[subpts /. Triangle[pts_] :> Triangle[Normalize /@ pts]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want a finer mesh, just use 3, 4 or 5 subdivisions.

Answer (score 0):

Discretize the unit sphere into triangles with `DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]]`, using the `MaxCellMeasure` or `MeshQualityGoal` options to choose the grid quality, and then calculate the centers of the resulting triangles (mesh primitives are all triangles in this case):

```
MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]], 2] /. Polygon[L_] :> Normalize[Mean[L]]
```

> {{0.222616, -0.858449, 0.462068}, {0.166477, -0.863634, 0.475837}, ..., {0.425092, 0.502648, 0.752757}, {0.451631, 0.406594, 0.794173}}

This is what the sphere discretization looks like with default parameters:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]]
```

[image]